# c++ boost::serialization setting a fixed class_id for a class

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'mm using boost to serialize and deserialize some classes

Like so:

```
boost::archive::xml_oarchive xmlArchive(oStringStream);

xmlArchive.register_type(static_cast<BaseMessage *>(NULL));
xmlArchive.register_type(static_cast<IncomingTradeMessage *>(NULL));
xmlArchive.register_type(static_cast<InternalRequestInfo *>(NULL));
xmlArchive.register_type(static_cast<InternalTradeTransInfo *>(NULL));

const BaseMessage* myMessage =message;

xmlArchive << make_nvp("Message", myMessage);
```

now my clasess get a class_id according to the order used, i dont want that, i want to control the Class_id's

so i can do something like

```
BOOST_SET_CLASS_ID(1234, BaseMessage);
```

and everywhere in my project BaseMessage would have class_id of 1234.

How can i do such a thing

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this?

Comment: im using it to comunicate between C# and C++ (over tcp)
and i want that attribute not to depend on the order the archive sees the classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you use `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID` or similar instead? I.e.

```
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(IncomingTradeMessage, "IncomingTradeMessage")
...
```

It will use some more bandwidth since strings are transmitted rather than integers, but it will solve your problem.

Refer to [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#export) and [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#export) for more info.

**EDIT:**

This compile just fine:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

class Foo {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & dummy1;
    }

    int dummy1;

public:
    virtual ~Foo() {}
};

class Bar : public Foo {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        // serialize base class information
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Foo>(*this);
        ar & dummy2;
    }

    int dummy2;
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(Foo, "Foo")
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(Bar, "Bar")

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    Foo *f = new Bar;
    oa << f;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Hellfrost: Can you be more specific? What errors does it give? And what Boost version and compiler are you using? I updated my answer to include a working example (it compiles, I tested).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is applicable in your case (if your question is specifically seeking mechanisms in boost or not), but how about strings? There's no boost facility like this that I know, but I've apply this kind of solution to our code base:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
const char* my_type_id()
{
    return "Unknown";
}

#define REGISTER_TYPE(some_type)            \
    template <> inline                      \
    const char* my_type_id<some_type>()     \
    {                                       \
        return #some_type;                  \
    }

REGISTER_TYPE(int)
REGISTER_TYPE(std::string)

int main()
{
    // displays "int"
    cout << my_type_id<int>() << endl;

    // displays "std::string"
    cout << my_type_id<string>() << endl;

    // displays "Unknown" - we haven't registered char
    cout << my_type_id<char>() << endl;
}
```

It's basically reinventing RTTI which, if you can use for production builds, makes this above solution unnecessary. We couldn't do this as it was for a software development kit and we didn't want to assume that everyone using it would have RTTI enabled.

If you need integers instead of strings, then it's easy enough to adapt this:

```
template <class T>
int my_type_id()
{
    return -1;
}

#define REGISTER_TYPE(some_type, type_code) \
    template <> inline                      \
    int my_type_id<some_type>()             \
    {                                       \
        return type_code;                   \
    }

REGISTER_TYPE(int, 1234)
REGISTER_TYPE(std::string, 4567)
```

You could even avoid the overhead of a function call and just generate a class that stores these type-associated integral values as an enumerated constant (guaranteed to be an rvalue).